# Representations of $I_h$

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups

I have been trying to solve this question and getting nowhere:

The icosahedral group comes equipped with a 3-dimensional representation. What is it? It is irreducible?

Any hints? I know what the representations of $A_5$ look like, but can't do more than that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two distinct, $3$-dimensional, irreducible representations of $A_5$. They have the same image in $\mathrm{GL}_3(\mathbb{R})$ and differ by an outer automorphism of $A_5$.

Both of them correspond to the realization of $A_5$ as the group of symmetries of a icosahedron (or, equivalently, of a dodecahedron): in fact, it is no difficult to see that there are no non-trivial subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that are invariant for all the symmetries.

For more details, you can have a look at

W. Fulton-J. Harris: *Representation Theory*, p. 29.

Comment: I was wondering about $I_h$ though, not $A_5$. That one has four 3-dimensional representations right?

Comment: $I_h$ is just $A_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, so its irreducible characters are obtained by multiplying those of $A_5$ by the two irreducible characters of $\mathbb{Z}_2$.